Issue in HypergeometricPFQ function:
I have a solution from integral:
A = Integrate[x^n*(1 + x)^n*Exp[-n*x^2] /. n -> 1, {x, 0, Infinity}] //Expand

(*1/2 + Sqrt[π]/4*)

%//N
(*0.943113*)

Then I have a general solution from integral:
B = Integrate[x^n*(1 + x)^n*Exp[-n*x^2], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
Assumptions -> n > 0] // Expand // FunctionExpand

(*-((n^-n π Csc[
n π] HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 - n/2, 1 - n/2}, {3/2, 
 1 - n}, -n])/(2 Gamma[-n])) + 
 1/2 n^(-(1/2) - n)
Gamma[1/2 + n] HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 - n/2, -(n/2)}, {1/2, 
1/2 - n}, -n] + (
 2^(-2 - 2 n)
Gamma[-(1/2) - n] Gamma[
1 + n] HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 + n/2, 1 + n/2}, {1 + n, 
3/2 + n}, -n])/Sqrt[π]*)

$$-\frac{n^{-n} \pi  \csc (n \pi ) \, _2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{2},1-\frac{n}{2};\frac{3}{2},1-n;-n\right)}{2 \Gamma (-n)}+\frac{1}{2} n^{-\frac{1}{2}-n} \Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{2}+n\right) \, _2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{2},-\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}-n;-n\right)+\frac{2^{-2-2 n} \Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{2}-n\right) \Gamma (1+n) \,
   _2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{n}{2},1+\frac{n}{2};1+n,\frac{3}{2}+n;-n\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}$$
As we can see, it consists of 3 parts.In the first term when n=1 I get Indeterminate,To eliminate the singularity, I substitute:$$\Gamma (-n)=-\frac{\pi  \csc (n \pi )}{\Gamma (1+n)}$$
Plot[{Gamma[-n], -((π Csc[n π])/Gamma[1 + n])}, {n, -3, 3}, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, {Black, Dashed}}]
(*Are equal*)

Plot[{-((n^-n π Csc[
 n π] HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 - n/2, 1 - n/2}, {3/2, 
  1 - n}, -n])/(2 Gamma[-n])), 1/2  n^-n  Gamma[
1 + n]  HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 - n/2, 1 - n/2}, {3/2, 
 1 - n}, -n]}, {n, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, {Black, Dashed}}] 
(*Are equal*)

we see on the plots functions are equal then with substituting only for first term I have:
$$\frac{1}{2} n^{-n} \Gamma (1+n) \, _2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{2},1-\frac{n}{2};\frac{3}{2},1-n;-n\right)+\frac{1}{2} n^{-\frac{1}{2}-n} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+n\right) \,
   _2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{2},-\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}-n;-n\right)+\frac{2^{-2-2 n} \Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{2}-n\right) \Gamma (1+n) \,
   _2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{n}{2},1+\frac{n}{2};1+n,\frac{3}{2}+n;-n\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}$$
 FUNC = 1/2  n^-n  Gamma[1 + n]  HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 - n/2, 1 - n/2}, {3/2, 1 - n}, -n] + 
 1/2  n^(-(1/2) - n)*Gamma[1/2 + n]  HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 - n/2, -(n/2)}, {1/2, 
  1/2 - n}, -n] + (
 2^(-2 - 2 n)*Gamma[-(1/2) - n] Gamma[
 1 + n] HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 + n/2, 1 + n/2}, {1 + n, 
  3/2 + n}, -n])/Sqrt[π];

 FUNC /. n -> 1
 (*1/2 + Sqrt[π]/4 - (1 - E + E (-(1/E) + Sqrt[π]/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[π] (1 - Erf[1])))/(4 E)*)

FUNC for n=1 I have :$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{4}-\frac{1-e+e \left(-\frac{1}{e}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } (1-\text{erf}(1))\right)}{4 e}$, but it should be: $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{4}$   ?
With Numerics works fine:
 {N[FUNC /. n -> 1 + 10^-100, 100], N[FUNC /. n -> 1 + 10^-100, 100], N[1/2 + Sqrt[π]/4, 100]}

 (* {0.9431134627263790068245418708352862956993873640305967820534519474632278211477580453437376641846361663, 0.9431134627263790068245418708352862956993873640305967820534519474632278211477580453437376641846361663, 0.9431134627263790068245418708352862956993873640305967820534519474632278211477580453437376641846361664}*)

Can someone explain to me where I made a mistake?

It seems to be the strange behavior of HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 - n/2, 1 - n/2}, {3/2, 1 - n}, -n] in FUNC that cause the problem. The following are the codes showing that:
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

NLimit[FUNC, n -> 1]
(*0.943114*)
N@A
(*0.943113*)
NLimit[B, n -> 1]
(*0.943113*)

NLimit[#, n -> 1] & /@ List @@ Expand@FUNC
(*{0.436706, 0.443114, 0.0632937}*)

List @@ Expand@FUNC /. n -> 1 // N
(*{0.5, 0.443113, 0.063294}*)

So the first part of Expand@FUNC leads to the difference, and it contains HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 - n/2, 1 - n/2}, {3/2, 1 - n}, -n].
HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 - n/2, 1 - n/2}, {3/2, 1 - n}, -n] /. n -> 1
(*1*)

HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 - n/2, 1 - n/2}, {3/2, 1 - n}, -n] /. 
 n -> 1.0000001
(*0.873412*)

NLimit[HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 - n/2, 1 - n/2}, {3/2, 1 - n}, -n], 
 n -> 1]
(*0.873412*)

and the plot also suggests that
Plot[HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 - n/2, 1 - n/2}, {3/2, 1 - n}, -n], {n, 
  1 - 1*^-2, 1 + 1*^-2}]



It's NOT a strange behavior of HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 - n/2, 1 - n/2}, {3/2, 1 - n}, -n]. HypergeometricPFQ works fine.
I made a mistake assuming FUNC/.n->1 is Equal to: Limit[FUNC,n->1].,but is not true in this case.
Let:
 S1 = 1/2*n^-n*Gamma[1 + n]*HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 - n/2, 1 - n/2}, {3/2, 1 - n}, -n]; 

 S2 = 2^(-2 - n)*n^-n*Gamma[1/2 - n/2]*Gamma[1 - n/2]*Gamma[1 + n]* HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2 - n/2, 1 - n/2}, {3/2, 1 - n}, -n];

 Plot[{S1, S2}, {n, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, {Black, Dashed}}](*Are equal*)

 S1 /. n -> 1(*Is NOT true!*)
 (*1/2*)
 Limit[S1, n -> 1](*Can't Compute! Gives a Input*)

 S2 /. n -> 1(* Indeterminate! *)
 Limit[S2, n -> 1, GenerateConditions -> False]

 (*(Sqrt[Pi]*(2*Derivative[{0, 0}, {0, 1}, 0] 
 [HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{0, 1/2}, {3/2, 0}, -1] + Derivative[{0, 1}, {0, 0}, 0][HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{0, 1/2}, {3/2, 0}, -1] + 
 Derivative[{1, 0}, {0, 0}, 0][HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{0, 1/2}, {3/2, 0}, -1]))/8)*)

 N[%, 50]
 (*0.43670603320310675634986685903296325133862492170315*)


$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

A = Integrate[x^n*(1 + x)^n*Exp[-n*x^2] /. n -> 1, {x, 0, Infinity}]

(* 1/4 (2 + Sqrt[π]) *)

(B = Assuming[n > 0,
    Integrate[
     x^n*(1 + x)^n*Exp[-n*x^2], {x, 0, Infinity}]]) // TraditionalForm


Convert the HypergeometricPFQ to HypergeometricPFQRegularized
(B2 = B /. HypergeometricPFQ[{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}, z_] :>
      Gamma[c]*Gamma[d]*
       HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{a, b}, {c, d}, z] //
    FullSimplify) // TraditionalForm


Verifying,
B == B2 // FullSimplify

(* True *)

The limit is very slow:
(lim = Limit[B2, n -> 1] // Normal) // TraditionalForm // AbsoluteTiming


Although this form of the limit is not convenient, it is numerically correct
A == lim // N[#, 50] &

(* True *)

Plot[Evaluate[Tooltip /@ {A, B2}], {n, 3/4, 5/4},
 GridLines -> {{1}, None},
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed],
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"A", "B2"}, {.8, .8}]]


